# with Pandas removing substring of the string in a column, when another column contains this substring

Tags: python, pandas

From this Pandas data frame:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo_abc', 'bar_def', 'ghi'], 'b': ['foo', 'bar', 'yah']})`

```
    a               b
0   foo_abc         foo
1   bar_def         bar
2   ghi             yah
```

I want to, probably with regex, remove the string in `b` column from string of `a` column to produce

```
     a             b     c
0   foo_abc      foo    abc
1   bar_def      bar    def
2   ghi          yah    ghi
```

How could I do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replace` with `strip` in list comprehension:

```
df['c'] = [a.replace(b, '').strip('_') for a, b in zip(df['a'], df['b'])]
print (df)
         a    b    c
0  foo_abc  foo  abc
1  bar_def  bar  def
2      ghi  yah  ghi
```

Solution with `re.sub`:

```
df['c'] = [re.sub('^({}_)'.format(b), '', a) for a, b in zip(df['a'], df['b'])]
```

Comment: Good to first able to see how to use `zip`. I rephrased your answer and got the same result: `df['c'] = [re.sub('^({}_)'.format(b), '', a) for a, b in zip(df['a'], df['b'])]`